# Zero knowledge proof that ElGamal ciphertext encrypts the opening of Pedersen commitment

Tags: public-key, commitments

Given ElGamal ciphertext for a message $m$ with a random $r$ as $(c_1,c_2) \gets (g^r, g^my^r)$ for a public key $y$, and a Pedersen commitment $C \gets g^xh^r$, I have been able to create a proof that $c_2$ and $C$ have equal discrete logs using Chaum-Pedersen proof of equal dlogs, but I'm stuck on how to prove that $c_1$ uses the same $r$ used in $c_2$ or $C$?

Comment: Why would you want to prove that the same $r$ is used? Typically, you will want to prove that it's the same $m$. However, different values of $r$ should be used, in order to claim the the encryption and commitment schemes remain secure.

Comment: @Yehuda Lindell: shouldn't randomness reuse be ok in most applications as long as independent public keys (h and y) are used?

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau I don't know. You would have to prove that using the same randomness does not interfere with indistinguishability. I am sure that you cannot do this at the level of encryption and commitments (based on the definitions only). The question is whether you could prove this directly based on DDH or the like. I don't know and one would have to try (these things often fail in the reduction...).

Comment: it is relatively straightforward to prove that the pair (ciphertext, commitment) with the same randomness, as in his question, is still computationally binding and IND CPA secure, under DDH. But yes, this can of course not be done at the commitment and encryption level, it is just a general property of the randomisability in DDH groups which makes randomness reuse a general (and quite commonly used) technique which usually works well in the reduction.